# My discord bot answer the prefix even without the command

Tags: node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

Also "/tts" isn't working, bot only writes even with the tss permision.

```
const prefix = "!";


bot.on('message', message => {
if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(new RegExp(' ', 'g'));
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

const user = message.author;

  if (command == "stretch" || "sr"){
    message.channel.send(user.username + ' your stretch reminder was 

activated!', tts=true);
        }
  });
```

Comment: Try removing unnecessary { } begins at the return;

Comment: I did but sadly the issue still. I also removed some parts of the code (you can see that I edited the post), and the problem still so it has nothing to do with the parts I took out.It seems right, idk what is getting wrong.

Comment: Now at least it's only answering the right prefix, but still answering it without any command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Bot answers even without command

The problem is from `command == "stretch" || "sr"`. It check if the `command` is `stretch` or `sr` exists. Since 'sr' is not undefined, it's always true and the bot will respond with commands other than that 2 ones. So, you can change the code to `command == 'stretch' || command = 'sr'`.

## 2. tts isn't working

There's no problem. It's discord bug and there's nothing available about that.

Comment: Man, you're awesome, it really fixed! Thank you very much! When I get 15 reputation I'll be back to upvote your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with `split`
Split accept regex but that's not the correct way to insert a flag
Try `split(new RegExp(' ', 'g'))`

Comment: I changed it, the code still working, but still the same problem. Oh, I can not vote yet, but I tried! Thank you for helping man!